# Having trouble looping over potential outcomes in a list

Tags: python, list, loops, while-loop, mapping

I have the following code that loops over each sublist in the existing list. So it adds on the last element of each and maps it from A-B over each sub list.

```
existing_list = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4]]
A = [4,5, 6]
B = [5,6, 7]

for i in range(len(existing_list)):
    sublist = existing_list[i]
    for j in range(len(A)):
        if sublist[-1] == A[j]:
            sublist.append(B[j])

print(existing_list)

[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]
```

Lets assume that I now want to add duplicated elements to A,B but for each one I want to create a unique path. I am having trouble understanding where to go from here.

My desired output would be, if I changed the following elements to A/B.

```
existing_list = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4]]
A = [4,4,5, 6]
B = [5,6,6, 7]


[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7], [2, 3, 4,5, 6, 7],[2, 3, 4, 6, 7]]
```

Need help looping over and making a new list. Sorry this is my first post, I apologize if it is too intensive. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what "add duplicated elements to A,B but for each one I want to create a unique path." means? Also, this example you're showing looks quite random and pointless. If this is a simplification of a more specific problem you're trying to solve, maybe telling us the original problem would be better because I do not have the slightest idea what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Yes Simon, it is a simplisticated problem to a much bigger dataset. Essentially I have an existing dataset with thousands of paths from A-B (existing list). Given the data basic data mapping of each point (A&B) I essentially am trying to create a unique path for each possible point that connects on the path. So by adding a duplicate comparative to the 1st code that runs I want to create a new unique path. Apologize for the complexity. The duplicated elements in A: is the extra 4,6 comparitive to their only being 1 path with 4 being 4,5.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a recursive function like so:

```
existing_list = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4]]

A = [4,4,5, 6]
B = [5,6,6, 7]


def map_multiple(sublist):
    subsets = []
    anyMatches = False
    for (key, value) in zip(A, B):
        if key == sublist[-1]:
            new_sets = map_multiple(sublist + [value])
            subsets.extend(new_sets)
            anyMatches = True
    if not anyMatches:
        return [sublist]
    return subsets

new_list = []
for i in range(len(existing_list)):
    sublist = existing_list[i]
    allSubsets = map_multiple(sublist)
    new_list.extend(allSubsets)

print(new_list)
```

Comment: Just make sure not to have n -> n or your program will get into an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Since `A` and `B` are mappings of pathways, I parsed them into a dictionary. Then I used a recursive function to loop through all the possible pathways wherever branches occur.

```
existing_list = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4]]
A = [4,4,5, 6]
B = [5,6,6, 7]

pathways = {}
for a, b in zip(A, B):
    if a not in pathways:
        pathways[a] = [b]
    else:
        pathways[a].append(b)

# creates a dict like this:
# paths = {
#     4: [5, 6],
#     5: [6],
#     6: [7]
# }

def get_paths(starting_path_list: list, pathways: dict) -> list[list]:
    all_path_lists = []

    while (end_num := starting_path_list[-1]) in pathways:
        if len(pathways[end_num]) == 1: # no branching
            starting_path_list += pathways[end_num]
        else:
            for path in pathways[end_num]: # branching
                all_path_lists += get_paths(starting_path_list + [path], pathways) # recursive call
            break
    else: # triggers if while loop ends without break
        all_path_lists.append(starting_path_list)
        
    return all_path_lists

new_list = []
for sublist in existing_list:
    new_list += get_paths(sublist, pathways)

print(new_list)
# prints: [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7], [2, 3, 4,5, 6, 7],[2, 3, 4, 6, 7]]
```

As with all recursion, you need to be careful to not create infinite loops. Here, you need to make sure that the pathways don't have any circular structure within them.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to be doing this on very large lists, you might want to use dictionaries to leverage direct access to sublists.

For example:

- Build a dictionary containing the sublists with a key that corresponds to the last number in each sublist. Take into account that there may be multiple sublists ending with the same value. so values in that dictionary will be lists of sublists (ending with the same value)
- This (`ends`) dictionary will allow you to extend the sublists by moving them from one ending key to another after adding an a->b link.
- It will also allow you to add multiple copies to the same ending key when an `a` links to multiple `b`s
- To make processing of A->B links easier, you can form a dictionary with each distinct `a` as the key and a list of corresponding `b`s as values (`ABPaths`)
- with these two dictionaries, the expansion process will simply be to move all lists ending with an `a` value to all ending keys (`b`s) for as many `b` values as needed (which will implicitly make duplicate paths)
- In the end the values in the `ends` dictionary will be all the paths

...

```
existing_list = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4]]
A = [4,4,5,6]
B = [5,6,6,7]

ends = dict()
for sublist in existing_list:
    ends.setdefault(sublist[-1],[]).append(sublist)

print(ends) # {4: [[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4]]}

ABPaths = dict()
for a,b in zip(A,B):
    ABPaths.setdefault(a,[]).append(b)

print(ABPaths) # {4: [5, 6], 5: [6], 6: [7]}

for a,bs in ABPaths.items():
    aEnds = ends.pop(a)
    for b in bs:
        ends.setdefault(b,[]).extend( e+[b] for e in aEnds )

existing_list = [p for paths in ends.values() for p in paths]

print(existing_list)
# [[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7], [2, 3, 4, 6, 7], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 
   [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]
```

*Note that this assumes that the A->B links only go to larger numbers (i.e. each value in B is larger than the corresponding value in A) which is true in your example but may not be so in your actual data*